# iOS 360 Video using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

I have an app that uses OpenGL ES 3.0 to play 360 Videos using a sky sphere implementation. I want to use OpenGL ES 2.0 to support more devices.

In ViewController.swift I create the EAGLContext in the method setupContext() and it works with .OpenGLES3 but when I try to use .OpenGLES2 I only see a black screen. There are no error messages and I am unable to discern what API functions are not supported in OpenGL ES 2.0.

```
context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES3)
EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(context)
```

How can I use OpenGL ES 2.0 to display 360 videos using a sky sphere? The main implementation is in Skysphere.swift. Thanks.

Sample app is found here: https://github.com/devinshively/TestVideoPlayer

Comment: Why not just load a sphere mesh and texture map the video? Instead of using Sky Sphere implementation. This way you can easily support older devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that OpenGL 3 automatically infers the pixel width and height. To use OpenGL 2 I needed to define the pixel buffer attributes kCVPixelBufferWidthKey and kCVPixelBufferHeightKey. I updated the test repo with the fix.

```
let pixelBufferAttributes = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
                                       kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String : 1024,
                                      kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String : 512]
```